# PyTorch GPU install with 11.2 CUDA

Tags: pytorch

How to install PyTorch if my CUDA version is 11.2 and CudNN version is 8.1.0?

Offical documentation at https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/ suggests only CUDA 10.2 and 11.3 versions.

Should I try to install it with v10.2 with next command?

```
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch
```

Won`t it have any incompatible version problems in the future?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell[1], PyTorch does not provide precompiled libraries for CUDA 11.2. You would have to compile it yourself. [For that, read this section of PyTorch Github's README.](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch#from-source)

[1]: I think so because on a similar question posed on PyTorch forums, one of the moderators said the same thing - https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/want-to-install-pytorch-for-custom-cuda-version-cuda-11-2/141159/2

edit: You can install PyTorch compiled for CUDA v11.1. In my case, it seems to work without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

There were some mentions about higher version doesn't work.

So, I installed **python 3.8.**

Then, I installed as below.

**conda install -y pytorch==1.12.0 torchvision==0.13.0 -c pytorch**

CUDA 11.2 with pytorch gpu works fine.

I confirmed it with nvidia-smi.